# How do I insert "padding" between two parts of the string?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a string

```
string totalAmount = "100";
string price = "Price";
ALPHA = Price + totalAmount
```

I know that one line of the docket can have 42 characters.
I want to print this on a docket such that the "Price" is on the left hand side of the docket and the "totalAmount" is on the right hand side.

How would I do this?

Comment: `alpha = "Price" + (insertPaddingFunction(42 - (Price.Length + totalAmount.Length))) + totalAmount;`

so something similar to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PadRight` should help you in this case.

```
string totalAmount = "100";
string price = "Price";
string result = price.PadRight(42 - totalAmount.Length) + totalAmount;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `String.PadLeft` / `String.PadRight` methods of the .net Framework if you use a font like Courier that have the same width for each character.

```
string totalAmount = "100".
ALPHA = "Price" + totalAmount.PadLeft(37, " ");
```

Comment: this will fail if `totalAmount < 100` or `totalAmount > 999`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.PadRight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34d75d7s(v=vs.110).aspx) and [String.PadLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk6ydzx(v=vs.110).aspx) to achive this.

```
string totalAmount = "100".PadLeft(37).
ALPHA = "Price" + totalAmount
```